# Why is ngrx storing only first element of an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, ngrx

I have an array that I have received from my REST service and am trying to store it in my ngrx store. Looking in my reducer, I can print out to the console each element of the array. However as soon as I store it in the state, it is reduced to a single element.

Here is the array I get in the reducer:

```
[
  {"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"},
  {"key3": "value3", "key4": "value4"},
  {"key5": "value5", "key6": "value6"},
  {"key7": "value7", "key8": "value8"}
]
```

Here is the code I am using in my reducer:

```
switch (action.type) {
    ...
    case actions.GET_ITEMS_COMPLETE:
      console.log('the array');
      console.log(action.items);
      console.log('indiviual items');
      console.log(action.items[0]);
      console.log(action.items[1]);
      console.log(action.items[2]);
      console.log(action.items[3]);
      return {...state,
        items: action.items
      };
      ...
}
```

Note that I am able to print each element of the array to the console without issue, but when I print the array and inspect the state once the reducer has finished, I see the array as follows:

```
[{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}]
```

Can anyone please explain why the other 3 elements were inexplicably removed from the array?

**UPDATE**
As requested here are the actions, effect, selector, and service that are being used with the reducer to persist the items onto the state:

**Actions**

```
export const GET_ITEMS = '[Items] GET_ITEMS';
export const GET_ITEMS_COMPLETE = '[Items] GET_ITEMS_COMPLETE';
export const GET_ITEMS_ERROR = '[Items] GET_ITEMS_ERROR';
export class GetItemsAction implements Action {
  readonly type = GET_ITEMS;

  constructor() { }
}
export class GetItemsCompleteAction implements Action {
  readonly type = GET_ITEMS_COMPLETE;

  constructor(public items: Array<Item>) { }
}
export class GetItemsErrorAction implements Action {
  readonly type = GET_ITEMS_ERROR;

  constructor(public error: Response) { }
}
```

**Effect**

```
  @Effect()
  getItems$ = this.actions$
    .ofType(itemActions.GET_ITEMS)
    .map(action => itemActions.GetItemsAction)
    .switchMap(() => {
      return this.api.item.getAll()
        .map(returnedItems => new itemActions.GetItemsCompleteAction(returnedItems))
        .catch(error => Observable.of(new itemActions.GetItemsErrorAction(error)))
    });
```

**Selector**

```
export function getItems(): Selector<AppState, Array<Item>> {
  return state$ => state$.map(state => state.item.items);
}
```

**Service**

```
@Injectable()
export class ItemService {
  itmes$: Observable<Array<Item>>;

  constructor(private store$: Store<AppState>) {
    this.items$ = store$.let(getItems());
  }

  getItems() {
    this.store$.dispatch(new GetItemsAction());
  }

}
```

**UPDATE 2**
Found the problem in one of the subscriptions to my item object. There was a splice in there, as seen below, that was removing all but the first element. Now my question is how did this splice from a subscription modify my state? Isn't the state in ngrx supposed to be immutable?

```
this.itemService.items$.subscribe(value => this.items = value.splice(1,3));
```

Comment: does this work: items: [...action.items]

Comment: no, I still only get the first element of the array in my state

Comment: Can you provide your state and actions?

Comment: @Amsakanna Updated with the code samples requested

Answer (score 0):

Brandon,

I know the docs say the store is immutable, but that hasn't been my experience. Maybe I'm missing something. I've lost too much time to a bug that looks exactly like this one.

To make it immutable you have to use a third party package. Perhaps Immutable.js, or ngrx-store-freeze.

Answer (score 0):

The code above would not modify your ngrx state, it would modify your component's state, specifically the components `items` property.

Comment: That was the intent, not the actual effect. The code above definitely modified my actual store, not just the component.